# How to read and change HTTP traffic on-the-fly on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, http

I need a method that would allow me to read all the HTTP traffic on a local machine, and to change this traffic on-the-fly.  Basically, I need to change the content on any web page opened in any browser at the machine.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For debugging/troubleshooting, or in production?

For debugging. [fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) lets you do this with scripts

For production use, you probably want to implement a [Layered Service Provider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_Service_Provider) (which I assume Fiddler2 does)

Comment: Thanks! This realy can be, what i need!

Answer (score 0):

Thought: Don't do it.

If you need this for corporate environment, use mandatory proxy with some URL scanning and redirection.

Comment: hi, proxy not work with my case, because my program must work without setup, if i use proxy then users need setup browser settings to set proxy.

Comment: There is also a thing called transparent proxy. Though I think it is evil. Much like modifying people's traffic on the fly. Also, if your "clients" will be using HTTPS then you cannot do what you want anyway because all of the traffic will be encrypted.

Comment: with transparent proxy can read and change all http traffic without any setup, i mean do i can setup in system transparent proxy thru program?

Answer (score 0):

You can run [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) locally as a proxy server, and define your content or URL rewrite rules it in.